# How do I extend Node fs.WriteStream in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

I am writing a class that extends Node's `fs.WriteStream` and generates a temporary file for the path instead of using a user-provided path:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import tmp = require('tmp');
export class TmpWriteStream extends fs.WriteStream {
  // Define some other properties
  constructor () {
    super(tmp.fileSync().name); // Error
    // Initialize other properties
  }
}
```

But, when I attempt to compile to javascript, I get the error:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableOptions | undefined'.`

It doesn't seem to want me to pass in `path` as a string to the `WriteStream` constructor, but when I look at the source code for `fs.WriteStream`, it appears to take two options, `path` and `options`: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L2160 (line 2160).

How can I extend `WriteStream` in such a way that I can pass in the path as a string like this?

Comment: I don't know what version do you have, but in my case WriteStream only receive options object.

Comment: Same - That's the problem. But fs.createWriteStream accepts a string path (or a buffer) and passes it to new WriteStream(path, options) -- so I'm trying to figure out how to extend the same WriteStream object that fs.createWriteStream is using. My version of Node is 9.8.0.

Comment: Definitely looks like the definition is wrong. [Here's](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v8/index.d.ts#L3018) the definition for `fs.WriteStream`, which extends [`stream.Writable`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v8/index.d.ts#L5379), who's constructor only accepts an options object. It may be worth opening an issue in that repo for this. In the meantime, you can always cast the argument as `any` or use `// @ts-ignore` comments to get rid of the error for now.